# Search text in specific position in textline, return whole line if find

Tags: c#

I am trying to return a textline from my textfile into the console, if the line contains a specific value(text), in a specific position. Each line in textfile splits into array containing 2 elements. The user input value should be compared with element[0] in each line, and if it matches then print out the whole line.

```
string findPoint = Console.ReadLine();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(directory);
WorldMap view = new WorldMap();

while ((findPoint= sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
     string[] separate = findPoint.Split('.');
     view.Point= separate[0];
     view.Grade= separate[1];
}
```

As you see above, the line is separated in two elements,  and what's left is the comparsion of findPoint and separate[0].

The code below is not working, unfortuantely. But it may help you understand what i'm trying to perform.

```
if (findPoint == separate[0])
{
 Console.WriteLine("lines containing specific word");
}
```

Comment: if findPoint  does not contain a point separate[0] = whole line

Comment: Can you post some input data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you are populating the findPoint string twice.  Once with:

```
string findPoint = Console.ReadLine();
```

And then when you read in the line to compare:

```
while ((findPoint= sr.ReadLine()) != null)
```

Use a different variable for the second.  Then your compare in the if should work.  Show some data examples so that we can see what things look like.

Comment: Finally works..Thank you! May I ask how it would be possible with date? Because now, user input have to look identically as the element in array, if printed.

Comment: What do you mean possible with date?  Show me what the array looks like and what the user input for date looks like.